# whats the meaning of this 'Data Frame' object is not callable'

Tags: python

I want to create a hist graph with these numerical columns, but I don't know why I keep getting this error "TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable"

```
df_num = train_df[['Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare']]
df_num.head()

for i in df_num.columns:
    
    plt.hist(df_num(i))
    plt.title(i)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You are treating `df_num` as a function when you do `df_num(i)` and it is not

Comment: What do you understand from that error? Have you done any debugging? Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score 2):

`df_num(i)` is attempting to call a function `df_num` with the argument `i`. You want `df_num[i]` instead.